# The reason behind red drop effect

Tags: plant-physiology, photosynthesis

I was reading about Emersion effect on Wikepedia, I was not able to correlate our current knowledge of photosynthesis with this effect,

First red drop effect

> When Emerson exposed green plants to differing wavelengths of light,
> he noticed that at wavelengths of greater than 680 nm the efficiency
> of photosynthesis decreased abruptly despite the fact that this is a
> region of the spectrum where chlorophyll still absorbs light

**My Query** is  this abrubt drop in rate of photosynthesis after 680 nm is because as PS1 absorbs wavelength greater than 680 nm till 700 nm , and PS1 does not evolve oxygen or fix Carbon dioxide? so rate of photosynthesis is very small at this point, as to reduce NADPH2 in Z scheme , photosystem 1 needed electron of Photosystem 2 , without electron of photosystem 2 it will not be able to reduce NADP, isn't it, I am very skeptic about this explanation, is it right?

Secondly it mentions

> When the plants were exposed to short-wavelength light, (less than 660
> nm), the efficiency also decreased.

Is this decrease in rate because of Photosystem 2 gets most activated at 680 nm and antenna molecules which broadens the spectrum as not very efficient result in decreased in rate of photosynthesis???

[image]

This graph is also adding to my confusion if PS1 active at FAR RED LIGHT only synthesizes ATP and not NADPH2 what does it have an equal bump( amplitude) like Red light(at which PS2 is active and carbon fixation in reality is happening here) So Amplitude of red light should have been greater than far red light

https://istudy.pk/emerson-enhancement-effect/ graph source

Comment: I recommend you to read taiz and zeigner's plant physiology. I read few years back it beautifully explains this concept. Right now, I'm preoccupied with some other question, if no one still answers this, I'll give a try